# Why can't I access JS object properties?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have the following function:

```
function getAggregateData(){
        var sums = new Object();


    $.getJSON("example.json.php", function(data) {
           //for each month
           c = 0;
            $.each(data, function(key, val, index) {
                  //for each store
                $.each(val, function(key2, val2, index2) { 
                      if(c == 0){
                         sums[key2] = val2; 
                      }
                      else{
                         sums[key2] += val2; 
                      }

                });
                c++
            });

    })
    return sums;
}
```

Which I then call as such:

```
var totals = getAggregateData();
```

But when I console log I am totally stumped:

```
console.log(totals)
```

reveals an object like this:

```
    store1  500
    store2  900
    store3  750
    and so on and so forth...
```

but when I do `console.log(totals['store1')` I get undefinded.

I have also tried `console.log(totals.store1)`

and `console.log(totals[0].store1)`

I am having some type of issue of scope, or I am not creating the object I think I am.

Comment: Where are these `console.log()` calls being run?

Comment: How does the raw JSON that comes from the server look?

Comment: you should avoid Object.new, use `var sums = {}` [see javascript-good-parts/bad-parts](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html). Also you are missing the var keyword in front of the `c` variable.

Comment: @quantas, right after var totals = getAggregateData();

Comment: @papirtiger {"1":{"store1":2450,"store2":1060,"store3":310},"2":{"store1":2460,"store2":1760,"store3":810}}

Comment: @quantas, presumably typed manually into the console

Comment: yeah without ahowing us what the JSON from the server looks like there is no way to see what is going wrong.  Try sticking something like console.log(data) right above c = 0;

Comment: The data is grouped by month and you want to aggregate it to an annual   total?

Comment: it is six months of data, the server returns as such:  Object { store1=2150, store2=1060, store3=310} for each of the six months.

Comment: @absentx: so all of your logs were called straight after the function?

Comment: @quantas, yes that is correct...except the new log reflecting the data was called from within.

Comment: I generated the following in my Chrome console: https://gist.github.com/olleicua/7163441

This is exactly what I would expect. This points to the likelyhood that your AJAX call isn't returning what you think.

Comment: @papirtiger, what happened to your answer? I saw it up for a bit on my mobile phone then it was gone. Did it not work out? Still struggling with this. If I construct and return sums within the ajax function, it returns properly, but when I run it as part of the outer getAggregateData function it seems to be out of scope. In FB I can fully expand the object when returned from within, but when returned from the outer function it just says "object"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function would be returning an empty object since it's not waiting for the AJAX call to finish.

If you tried doing console.log(totals.store1) on the last line inside your $.getJSON callback you'll *probably* get a result.

You'll need to put any code that requires data from "example.json.php" inside a callback that only gets run after the AJAX call has returned.

E.g.

```
function getAggregateData(){
    var sums = new Object();

    $.getJSON("example.json.php", function(data) {
       //for each month
       c = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key, val, index) {
              //for each store
            $.each(val, function(key2, val2, index2) { 
                  if(c == 0){
                     sums[key2] = val2; 
                  }
                  else{
                     sums[key2] += val2; 
                  }

            });
            c++
        });

        processAggregateData(sums);

    })
}

function processAggregateData(totals) {
    console.log(totals.store1);
}

getAggregateData();
```

Comment: This does indeed work. My earlier problem was of scope. But the scope issue continues to thwart me here. I need these values easily retrievable from outside. If I pass the object to processAggregateData, how do I then access say totals.store1 when I need to input it into a chart or some other place?

Comment: You could save it to a global variable by attaching it to the window object e.g. window.totals

Comment: Is that good practice though? I always hear that global JS variables are very bad...I'll do it if I have to, but just trying to always improve...scope is my biggest obstacle yet.

Comment: You could create an object that has those functions as methods, and keeps totals as a property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

given:

```
{
    "1": {
        "store1": 2450,
        "store2": 1060,
        "store3": 310
    },
    "2": {
        "store1": 2460,
        "store2": 1760,
        "store3": 810
    }
};
```

This should work if you intend to add the results for each store.

```
/**
* This functions need to be called when we have the data
*/
function processSums(obj){
    console.log(obj);
}

function getAggregateData(){

    var sums = {};

    $.getJSON("example.json.php", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(key, val, index){                
                    sums[key] = sums[key] || 0;
                    sums[key] += val;               
                });
            });
            // 4910
            processSums(sums);
    });

    return sums;
}

getAggregateData();
```

Comment: i deleted it because it did not really solve the core issue which is timing, but here it is